# Process nested hash to convert all values to strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have the following code which takes a hash and turns all the **values** in to strings.

```
def stringify_values obj
  @values ||= obj.clone

  obj.each do |k, v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      @values[k] = stringify_values(v)
    else
      @values[k] = v.to_s
    end
  end

  return @values
end
```

So given the following hash:

```
{
  post: {
    id: 123,
    text: 'foobar',
  }
}
```

I get following **YAML** output

```
--- &1
:post: *1
:id: '123'
:text: 'foobar'
```

When I want this output

```
--- 
:post: 
  :id: '123'
  :text: 'foobar'
```

It looks like the object has been flattened and then been given a reference to itself, which causes Stack level errors in my specs.

How do I get the desired output?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why the use of the instance variable?

Comment: So that every time it recurses over the method it appends the return result to the instance variable and builds it up with the object parameters

Comment: the instance variable messes it up because during a call to .each, the value of @result might change, so you end up appending data to the wrong place

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simpler implementation of `stringify_values` can be - assuming that it is always a Hash.  This function makes use of [`Hash#deep_merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge) method added by Active Support Core Extensions - we merge the hash with itself, so that in the block we get to inspect each value and call `to_s` on it.

```
def stringify_values obj
  obj.deep_merge(obj) {|_,_,v| v.to_s}
end
```

---

Complete working sample:

```
require "yaml"
require "active_support/core_ext/hash"

def stringify_values obj
  obj.deep_merge(obj) {|_,_,v| v.to_s}
end

class Foo
    def to_s
        "I am Foo"
    end
end

h = {
  post: {
    id: 123,
    arr: [1,2,3],
    text: 'foobar',
    obj: { me: Foo.new}
  }
}

puts YAML.dump (stringify_values h)
#=> 
---
:post:
  :id: '123'
  :arr: "[1, 2, 3]"
  :text: foobar
  :obj:
    :me: I am Foo
```

Not sure what is the expectation when value is an array, as `Array#to_s` will give you array as a string as well, whether that is desirable or not, you can decide and tweak the solution a bit.

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'deep_merge' for {:post=>{:id=>123, :text=>"foobar"}}:Hash`

Comment: @mudasobwa Its an extension in Rails active support.  OP's question is tagged with `rails`

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues. First: the `@values` after the first call would always contain an object which you cloned in the first call, so in the end you will always receive a cloned `@values` object, no matter what you do with the `obj` variable(it's because of `||=` operator in your call). Second: if you remove it and will do `@values = obj.clone` - it would still return incorrect result(deepest hash), because you are overriding existing variable call after call.

```
require 'yaml'

def stringify_values(obj)
  temp = {}
  obj.each do |k, v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      temp[k] = stringify_values(v)
    else
      temp[k] = v.to_s
    end
  end
  temp
end

hash = {
  post: {
    id: 123,
    text: 'foobar',
  }
}

puts stringify_values(hash).to_yaml

#=>
---
:post:
  :id: '123'
  :text: foobar
```

Comment: I see, so it was the instance variable causing the issue. Do you know why the output is different in that case?

Comment: Wish I could accept both but went with the one liner. All I can do is upvote yours

Comment: @CarlMarkham of course it's your decision, I am here to help, not to gain points and check marks :)

Comment: I've changed my downvote to an upvote. Thank you for improving your answer!

Comment: A good answer explains *why* a solution works. The purpose of Stack Overflow isn't to turn posters' broken code into working code, it's to help them understand why their code is broken and how to fix it, thereby making them better programmers. A code-only answer *might* accomplish that, but it's unlikely.

Comment: If you wish to get rid of last statement `temp` hanging on its own, you can give `{}.tap do |temp| ....end ` a try.  Interesting how `tap` can save us from using temporary variables.

Comment: @WandMaker never used `.tap` in my code(to get rid of temp vars I usually do `.each_with_object`), thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution without need of ActiveSupport, you can do this in one line using `each_with_object`:

```
obj.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),m| m[k] = v.to_s }
```

If you want to modify `obj` in place pass `obj` as the argument to `each_with_object`; the above version returns a new object.

Answer (score -1):

If you are as aware of converting values to strings, I would go with monkeypatching `Hash` class:

```
class Hash
  def stringify_values
    map { |k, v| [k, Hash === v ? v.stringify_values : v.to_s] }.to_h
  end
end
```

Now you will be able to:

```
require 'yaml'
{
  post: {
    id: 123,
    text: 'foobar'
  },
  arr: [1, 2, 3]
}.stringify_values.to_yaml
#⇒ ---
#  :post:
#    :id: '123'
#    :text: foobar
#  :arr: "[1, 2, 3]"
```

In fact, I wonder whether you really want to scramble `Array`s?