# Finding the words to the left and right of a string

Tags: ruby, string

I want to get the words to the left and right of a string. For example, if the entire string is:

```
"Programming is my passion"
```

I want to extract the words to the left and right of `"is"`: `"Programming"` and `"my"`.

Comment: How should this function work if the sentence is instead `"Programming is my passion because it is very interesting"`, since there are now two instances of "is" in the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(\w+) is (\w+)\b
```

Now take groups 1 and 2 of the match.

```
sentence = 'Programming is my passion'
word     = 'is'
matches  = sentence.match(/\b(\w+) #{word} (\w+)\b/)

matches[1] # => "Programming"
matches[2] # => "my"
```

---

The idea is:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\w+)` - as many word characters as possible, contained in a numbered group

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution;

```
str = "Programming is my passion"
word = "is"
words = str.split(/\W/)
index = words.index(word)
before, after = words[index-1], words[index+1] if index > 0
p before 
#=> "Programming"
p after
#=> "my"
```

Comment: [Hats off](http://askandyaboutclothes.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/HatTipCartoon.jpg) to noble SO user that up-voted this answer as up voting is becoming [rare](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34595416/794242)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
\b(\w+)\b\s+is\s+\b(\w+)\b
            ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex too:

```
(\S+)\s+is\s+(\S+)
```

DEMO: http://rubular.com/r/rAtgGuh7Oh

Answer (score 0):

with variables:

```
string = 'Programming is my passion'

matchers = string.match(/(?<before>\w+)?\s?is\s?(?<after>\w*)?/)

matchers[:before] # "Programming"
matchers[:after] # "my"

string = 'Programmingismy passion'
# same tesults
```

http://rubular.com/r/MvUFf9WVF7

Answer (score 0):

A solution without regular expressions but with [`each_cons()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

```
str = "Programming is my passion"

def neighbors(s, w)
  s.split(/\W/)
   .each_cons(3)
   .find   { |_,e,_| e == w }
   .reject { |e| e == w }
end

before, after = neighbors(str, 'is')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def neighbours str, pattern
  str.scan(/(\S*)\s+#{pattern}\s+(\S*)/).flatten
end

neighbours 'Programming is my passion', 'is'
#⇒ ["Programming", "my"]
```